# Perturbation Theory on $x^5+5x-5=0$

Tags: perturbation-theory

One of the questions in my exercises consists of a question on the perturbation theory. The question is to use the perturbation expansion to approximate the root of this equation; $$x^5+5x-5=0$$ How would I integrate $\epsilon$ into this function to simplify things. If anyone could recommend me a link on perturbation expansions I would also be really grateful.

Comment: I'm not entirely certain what you're asking, but perhaps start with a root of $x^2 + 5x - 6$ and apply the Newton-Raphson method?

Comment: Don't I have to use the expansion of x=x(0)+ϵx(1)+ϵ^2x(2), and input that into the equation. The problem I'm having is fitting ϵ into the original equation.

Comment: You can maybe see the equation as $\varepsilon x^5+x-1=0$ with $\varepsilon=0.2$ and make an asymptotic expansion starting with $x_0=1$.

Comment: I see, say I wanted to find the first three terms of that equation without equating it to zero, what would I do then.